# Which approach to use for bin merging either Bin packing algorithm or Knapsack?

Tags: java

I am merging bins with one target bin, say I have List of objects with weights {50,30,20,60,35,25,65}. I want to merge with the bin which is least occupied i,e 20 in this case. The max capacity of the bin is 80 . I want to get the combination of weights which should not exceed max capacity 80. Which algorithm I should use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of optimization algorithms like simulated annealing, ruin and recreate principle, Monte Carlo method, bruteforce etc.
If you need to solve such problems in Java you can write your own implementation or use libraries.

For example:

- [optaplanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/)
- [chip-n-salsa](https://github.com/cicirello/Chips-n-Salsa)
- [java simulated annealing package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jannealer/)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is knapsack gives back the combinations of all the weights which are equal or less than the total capacity ?